# Java Server Faces xhtml extension - overlapping with html files

Tags: xml, jsf, xhtml

In a project we use jsf. For mapping, xhtml extension is used.

But in the project we have some xhtml files, which are not jsf.
Just plain html with xml syntax.

When we request for these files, Faces Servlet intercepts naturally.

So we tried to change extension of these files to xml and later to html.
But in both cases, there were problems raised..

**In xml case:** browsers don't behave to the content as normal html in some cases.

**In html case:** browsers comment out xml tag, and do not run xml stylesheets.

We can not change xhtml extension mapping for jsf.

What can you suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: Found an extension named xht which seems a shorter version of xhtml. Trying it now.

Comment: +1 for good question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rename those plain HTML files to `.html` and use if necessary HTML5 doctype instead of XHTML doctype. Using XHTML "plain vanilla" (read: without any server side interaction) has **no utter value** in the client side. If the sole reason is being able to use and validate XML syntax, just use the HTML5 doctype.

#### See also:

- [What's the need for XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557827/whats-the-need-for-xhtml/3194601#3194601)
- [What are the advantages of creating web pages with XML instead of HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691289/what-are-the-advantages-of-creating-web-pages-with-xml-instead-of-html/3691291#3691291)
- [Should I start with HTML or XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989500/should-i-start-with-html-or-xhtml/1989527#1989527)
- [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5)

Comment: I tried that, but not solved. use with or without xhtml or html doc types, browsers interpret it as plain html. Some of xhtml files includes xml stylesheets and when i rename extension from xhtml to html those stylesheets are not been called. When checked html elements in firebug seeing those xml and xml stylesheets as commentted.

Comment: Using xht extension instead of xhtml solved my problem. Thanks.