# What happens to SEO ranking if website is made with XML & XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am making a website that uses client side XSLT to display XML data in HTML.

Will search engines understand?

### Possible alternative

Generate xHTML at server for search-engines and those browsers which don't support xslt.

Comment: XHTML is XML. Why not just use that?

Comment: 1) XSLT code will be cached on user side. 2) data in XML and json remains clean and small in size. 3) I can deliver different XSLT for different browser+language, so user gets only what he needs, no extra stuff.

Comment: You're right. Too bad HTML can't be cached, or clean, or differ by browser and language. ;)

Comment: Also you can check the discussion in [Current state of client-side XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597024/current-state-of-client-side-xslt/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search engines will most probably index the XML, if even that.

Most search engine bots do not support javascript, let alone XSL transformations.

Comment: As far as I know google bot will not do that either. Best use the [Webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) to find out.